# Responsive slider in large device

Tags: jquery, html, css, unslider

I'm using unslider slideshow , with media query i can handle responsive design in mobile and tablet . but in larger screen images and text go to left and right screen .
i don't want to give the wrapper a 960 width . i want to have view port in 100% width .

Here's my plunk :
http://plnkr.co/edit/qh3ZziqHyl6beU6jAuY5?p=preview

full screen plunk : http://run.plnkr.co/psXtV5yeFMRnUbNz/

```
.slide-img-2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 365px;
    top:91px;
}
.sl-banner-content{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
    top: 33%;
}

.slide-img-3{
    position: absolute;
    right: 422px;
    top:91px;
}
```

Any Advice ?

Comment: From the first link example it looks like a lot of elements are set to fixed sizes in px and fixed margin px, which probably creates some problems for your responsive results. I modified a ( changing things to width: 100%; height: auto; ) and it made things work better.. However, the second link where you show your full screen plunk doesn't seem to be working :( so I'm not exactly sure what your final result should look like to give 100% best advice imho